# Различие NPathComplexity и CyclomaticComplexity?

Tags: java

В чем различие NPathComplexity и CyclomaticComplexity? Если можно, на примере Java кода. Наткнулся на эти понятия, пока копался в PMD Warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Попробую объяснить. У нас есть метод:

```
private static boolean isSolder(int age, boolean isFemale) {
    boolean result;

    if (isFemale) {
        if (age < 18)
            result = false;
        else
            result = true;
    } else
        result = false;

    return result;
}
```

Чтобы посчитать его `CyclomaticComplexity` достаточно для каждого ветвления `(if,while,for,case)` добавлять к сложности + 1. В итоге получаем 2. Еще 1 нужно добавить для объявления самого метода. Итого 3.

С `NPathComplexity` немного сложнее. Эта метрика показывает, сколько существует путей в программе, по которым может быть выполнение. Чтобы было нагляднее, построим граф.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где:

вершина 0 - это условие `if (isFemale)`

вершина 6 - это условие `if (age < 18)`

легко подсчитать, что ациклических путей в данном графе всего 3. Это число и будет итоговой оценкой.

Comment: А если в методе будет несколько `if`, идущих подряд, будет учитываться тот, у которого наивысшая сложность, или сумма их сложностей (в каждом случае)?

Comment: Насколько я понял, они должны суммироваться